How to create a git workflow based on splitting your current branch into two, and later picking one to PR?
I've create a feature branch feature/CRM-123_some_feature, where CRM-123 is the Jira ticket ID.
I've tried doing it one way, and made a local commit. After testing, the performance was not great, so I've tried a different way, changing my code significantly and retesting.
Now I want to keep this experimental branch, switch back to my earlier code, and try modifying it.
So I kind of have two branches.  Later, I want to do a PR for one of them and merge back into develop.
I'm on the original feature/CRM-123_some_feature branch, but with new changes. I assume I could create a new branch, which will be based on my original one, using git checkout -b feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment1, and checking my updated code.
I could then checkout my first branch, and try various modifications to that, checking in the results.
When I come to merge with develop, and I merge feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment1, but not feature/CRM-123_some_feature, will the changes in feature/CRM-123_some_feature be missing from develop?
Or maybe I need three branches:
feature/CRM-123_some_feature
-- feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment1
-- feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment2

and need to merge one of the two experiment branches back into the original feature/CRM-123_some_feature branch and PR that, if PR'ing the experiment2 branch on its own will lose the original branches changes?
What is the simplest solution?

Keep in mind that branches are trivially cheap (just strings). So just keep trying stuff on different branches. If a road turns out to be a dead end but you want to keep some earlier commits, start a new branch off the last "good" commit in the series. Merging locally is fine too. When you're all done, you can straighten out the flow of commits before pushing. Also, there is no need to call these things feature/CRM-123 all the time; you only need to change to that name for the one you actually push for the PR, so that CI can see it and coordinate with Jira.

Basically what I'm saying is, the more you understand how ridiculously easy and cheap it is to make multiple branches, to roll back branches, to merge branches locally, to rearrange commits locally, etc., etc., the more obvious it will be to you how to do this sort of development nimbly in a way that suits the way your mind works.

Cheapness is not the issue, knowing how to do it without getting into a mess is the issue.  "straighten out the flow of commits" is the issue, specifically if you create branch A, then create branch B from branch A, then PR B, will it be missing changes in A it was based on?

Interesting, I didnt know you could change the name of a local branch, but looking it up, its possible with git branch -m newname.

Totally. A branch is literally just a string, a name. It has no extended "thing-ness" beyond that. Read up on git switch, git branch, git reset to get a feel for the incredible range of easy tools in your toolbox. Everything is undoable, everything is rearrangeable. Another cool thing to know is that if you do a bunch of work in the working tree that you haven't committed and you wish you had started a new branch for this work, you can. Or if you do multiple commits and wish they had been on a new branch, you can.

"if you create branch A, then create branch B from branch A, then PR B, will it be missing changes in A it was based on" Git isn't about "changes", it's about commits. Every commit is a snapshot of the entire project. Only one commit in a branch really matters: the last one. It expresses the current state of the project. The others are just states you saved along the way, just in case you needed to roll back. You could get rid of all of those if you wanted.

Thanks for the reply. Is this a yes or a no?  I think you are saying its a no, i.e. If I push banch B, it will have the changes from Branch A in it too (so I dont need to do any merging prior to PR.

If you have made further commits on feature/CRM-123_some_feature after creating feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment1, then the changes introduced by those commits won't be included when merging feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment1 into develop.
So, to visually represent the situation described above, the changes introduced by commits G and H won't be merged into develop when doing a PR from feature/CRM-123_some_feature to develop.
A -- B                       develop
      \
       C -- D -- G -- H      feature/CRM-123_some_feature 
             \
              E ----- F      feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment1

But, If your situation is the following, then every change introduced by feature/CRM-123_some_feature will be brought into develop when creating a PR from feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment1.
A -- B                       develop
      \
       C -- D                feature/CRM-123_some_feature 
             \
              E -- F         feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment1

Keep in mind that, when you merge a branch (feature) into another branch (develop), Git first determines the set of commits to merge by going from the head of the other branch up to the merge base (the commit where the two branches have diverged). Then, applies the commits' changes on top of the target branch.
So, in the first case, the commits that will concur to the merge will be F, E, D, C, and their changes will be applied on top of develop. Commits G and H will be excluded from the merge, because there is no path from F to B that can reach G and H (in Git commits only point to their parent(s)).

Great, so If in the first diagram, I only need to PR either H or F, no merging required, i.e C will be included whichever I PR.   This is easier than I suspected!  If I PR H, then I dont care about E and F, if I PR F, I dont care about G and H.

Ok, now im confused again. What am I merging to what?  Cant I just Push either feature/CRM-123_some_feature or feature/CRM-123_some_feature-experiment1 to origin and create a PR?

@JohnLittle a PR is basically a merge. So, yeah, you can do that. I've just updated my comment to make it easier.
